# NoClassDefFoundError with facebook android sdk 3.5

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using facebook android sdk 3.5. I have just updated the sdk to version 3.5 without making any changes in my code. I am not using any deprecated functions after migrating to version 3.5.

I am posting only relevant lines of logcat here.

```
11-17 18:04:35.676: E/AndroidRuntime(7647): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 18:04:35.676: E/AndroidRuntime(7647): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper
11-17 18:04:35.676: E/AndroidRuntime(7647):     at com.googlepages.vysakhp.barebone_fb.Barebone_fbActivity.onCreate(Barebone_fbActivity.java:222)
```

I using facebook android sdk as library project. My eclipse version is 4.3 kepler.

Thanks in advance.

Edit

Here is my code in line 222. It comes in onCreate method of an activity.

```
uihelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, null); //line 222
uihelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

I have used StatusCallback to receive events related to session in facebook sdk 3.0 without any problem. After moving to sdk version 3.5, I started facing seeing NoClassDefFoundError exceptions with StatusCallback. So removed the callback and replaced the instance of StatusCallback in line 222 with null.

Comment: Are you using the SDK jar or importing the project in Eclipse ?

Comment: show us your line 222 in Barebone_fbActivity please

Comment: clean both projects(library and your main project) make sure you have the right support library jar in both the projects, if not just download the latest support library(left click on a project, android tools - add support library)

Comment: @user1940676 I have already downloaded the latest support library. It didn't help me. I followed instructions in "http://grammarofdev.blogspot.in/2013/09/facebook-android-sdk-v35-tutorial.html" and used the version of support library that came with facebook android sdk 3.5. Even that didn't help me.

Comment: @AakashGoyal I am using facebook sdk as a library project just as it is mentioned in the Getting Started for Eclipse.

Comment: Is the support library located in the /libs folder?
You need to have the support library for the library project as well.

Comment: @user1940676 Yes support library is located in /libs folder for the facebook sdk. By the way my application does not use support library.

Comment: @user1940676 I have edited my question just as you said.

Comment: @user1940676 I tried downgrading to facebook android sdk 3.0.2 but still no luck. Same problem persists.

Comment: @VysakhPrem contact me by email

Answer (score 0):

The android-support-v4.jar inside your folder have different version than library in facebook SDK. Just copy the library android-support-v4.jar of facebook SDK in your project libs folder and add it into build path. Enjoy the solution hopefully it workds!!!